# Cobalt for Amazon Prime

Tags: licensing, cobalt, memory-footprint

We are planning to use a Cobalt port on our embedded platform to run applications like Amazon Prime along with YouTube. Is it possible to use it for applications other than YouTube?

If so, what is the expected run-time footprint of Cobalt?

Also, is there any licensing cost associated with Cobalt?

Comment: Please ask product questions at cobalt-dev@googlegroups.com where I'll be happy to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Cobalt can run any application that has been engineered to run within the Cobalt subset of HTML/CSS/WebAPI. It is unlikely that Amazon Prime Video will run out of the box on Cobalt, but it could be made to run with some effort.

Cobalt is open source, and has no licensing fee.

For YouTube, Cobalt currently takes about 130MB of CPU memory. GPU usage depends a lot on the image cache settings and UI resolution.

The binary is currently about 5MB stripped and compressed, 19MB uncompressed. Our ICU data is 2MB compressed, 6MB uncompressed. We have a couple different font options that take varying amounts of space. We can cover almost everything in 10MB of uncompressed fonts.

These numbers are all subject to significant change.